# If $x\mapsto f(x,y)$ and $y\mapsto f(x,y)$ is continuous differentiable, then whether $f(x,y)$ is continous?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Here is the question in my exercise.

> Let $f(x,y)$ be a function defined on a rectangle $[a,b]\times [c,d]$. Assume that for each fixed $y \in[c,d]$ the function $x\mapsto f(x,y)$ is a continuously differentiable function of $x$ on $[a,b]$; and for each fixed $x \in[a,b]$ the function $y\mapsto f(x,y)$ is a continuously differentiable function of $y$ on $[c,d]$. Can you conclude that $f(x,y)$ is a continuous function on the rectangle $[a,b]\times [c,d]$? If your answer is Yes then give a proof; if your answer is
> No then give a counterexample.

Here is my thinking: Fixed any point $P_0$ in $[a,b]\times [c,d]$. If $x\mapsto f(x,y)$ and $y\mapsto f(x,y)$ are both continuously differentiable, which means the partial deravatives $f_x$ and $f_y$ are continuous. So $f(x,y)$ is differentiable at $P_0$. Then $f(x,y)$ is continuous.

Is my thinking right? If it's wrong, what mistake I made?

Comment: “which means the partial derivatives $f_x$ and $f_y$ is continuous”. Wrong. All you know is that the partial derivative $f_x$ exists and $x\mapsto f_x(x,y)$ is continuous, but you don’t necessarily know $(x,y)\mapsto f_x(x,y)$ is continuous (i.e you don’t know that $f_x$ is continuous). An analogous issue with your other statement about $f_y$.

Comment: Cite the exact theorem used.  "If $f_x, f_y$ are continuously differentiable, then $f$ is differentiable."  Does that theorem have hypothesis that $f$ is continuous?

Comment: @peek-a-boo but y is fixed when dealing with $f_x(x,y)$, doesn't that mean y is a const at this moment and $x\mapsto f_x(x,y)$ is the same as $(x,y)\mapsto f_x(x,y)$?

Comment: @GEdgar "Does that theorem have hypothesis that f is continuous?" No. Only need the partial derivatives exist and are continuous. But if f(x,y) is differentiable, then it is continuous.

Comment: Please cite that theorem from a textbook or web page.  (Include the information in your question.)

Comment: For each **fixed $y$**,  $x\mapsto f_x(x,y)$ is a function of one variable, i.e a function $\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$. On the other hand, $(x,y)\mapsto f_x(x,y)$ is a function of two variables, i.e a function $\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}$ (or between subsets thereof). These are most certainly NOT the same thing (their domains obviously don’t match). Make sure you understand this distinction; it’s extremely important.

Comment: @GEdgar that’s a fairly standard theorem which OP has quoted correctly (though misusing it, since the hypotheses are not satisfied here), and I’m sure you (and almost everyone) know it; it’s proved in every decent multivariable calculus book (Spivak, Munkres etc). So, I don’t see what’s the point of editing that into the question

Comment: Why quote the exact theorem?  To help the OP answer the question "what mistake I made?"

Comment: @peek-a-boo what about the counterexample to this question?

Comment: @peek-a-boo I can understand the two functions are not same abstractly since their domains don't match, but not intuitively. What effect does the variable $y$ have on the function if $y$ is fixed and don't change? If possible, could you please offer an example to illustrate it?

Comment: To illustrate the difference (but not answering your question because we need to finesse the argument more), imagine a function which is constant on horizontal lines, but with arbitrary $y$ behaviour. In other words, consider any crazy function $g$ of one variable (e.g nowhere continuous or non-measurable or literally anything), and define $f(x,y)=g(y)$. Then $f$  doesn’t depend on $x$, so the $x$-partial is identically $0$, but obviously $f$ itself is a terrible function. This is why the domain matters. Of course, this function alone doesn’t answer your question, but should get you started.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Now I have totally understood the difference. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function
$$f(x,y):=\begin{cases}
\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}&\text{if }(x,y)\ne(0,0)\\0&\text{if }(x,y)=(0,0)\end{cases}$$
is infinitely differentiable on $\Bbb R^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$.

Moreover,
$$\forall x\in\Bbb R\quad f(x,0)=0,$$
so that $x\mapsto f(x,y)$ is infinitely differentiable on $\Bbb R$ for every $y\in\Bbb R$, including $y=0$. Similarly, $y\mapsto f(x,y)$ is infinitely differentiable on $\Bbb R$ for every $x\in\Bbb R$.

However, at $(0,0)$, $f$ has no limit (hence is not continuous), since
$$\lim_{x\to0}f(x,x)=\frac12\ne0=\lim_{x\to0}f(x,0).$$